# How to Use Package A* (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, a-star

I have downloaded A* package from http://rocketmandevelopment.com/blog/putting-a-into-code/. I have a problem about how to use the package of A*, because I just have the package.

- Do I have to create main.fla?
- What must I write in main.fla class? Grid.as, Cell.as, or AStar.as?

I'm sorry my English is bad. The point is, I don't know how to use the package. :D ##

Cell.as

```
package com.rocketmandevelopment.grid {
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import com.rocketmandevelopment.grid.pieces.Piece;
    import com.rocketmandevelopment.math.Vector2D;

    public class Cell {
    public var f:Number = 0;
    public var g:Number = 0;
    public var h:Number = 0;
    public var isClosed:Boolean = false;
    public var isOpen:Boolean = false;
    public var isWalkable:Boolean = true;

    private var _neighbors:Array;

    public function get neighbors():Array {
        if(!_neighbors) {
            _neighbors = [];
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x - 1, y - 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x, y - 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x + 1, y - 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x + 1, y));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x + 1, y + 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x, y + 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x - 1, y + 1));
            _neighbors.push(Grid.cellAt(x - 1, y));
            var len:int = _neighbors.length
            for(var i:int = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(_neighbors[i] == null) {
                    _neighbors.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return _neighbors;
    }

    public var parent:Cell;

    public function get position():Vector2D {
        return new Vector2D(_x, _y);
    }

    public var possibleActions:Array = [];
    public var visited:Boolean = false;
    private var _x:int;

    public function get x():int {
        return _x;
    }
    private var _y:int;

    public function get y():int {
        return _y;
    }

    public function Cell(x:int, y:int) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public function clear():void {
        f = 0;
        g = 0;
        h = 0;
        isClosed = false;
        isOpen = false;
        parent = null;
        isWalkable = true;
    }

    public function draw(g:Graphics, w:Number, h:Number):void {
        if(!isWalkable) {
            g.beginFill(0x000088);
        }
        g.drawRect(_x * w, _y * h, w, h);
        g.endFill();
    }

    public function reset():void {
        f = 0;
        g = 0;
        h = 0;
        isClosed = false;
        isOpen = false;
        parent = null;
    }

    public function toString():String {
        return "Cell(x: " + _x + " y: " + _y + ")"; // " f: "+ f +" g: "+g+" h: "+h + ")";
    }
}
```

Grid.as

```
package com.rocketmandevelopment.grid {
import flash.display.Graphics;

public class Grid {
    private static var theGrid:Grid;

    private var _height:int;

    private var _width:int;
    private var grid:Array;

    public function Grid(width:int, height:int) {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        grid = [];
        for(var x:int = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            grid[x] = [];
            for(var y:int = 0; y < _height; y++) {
                grid[x][y] = new Cell(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function cellAt(x:int, y:int):Cell {
        if((x >= 0 && x < theGrid.grid.length) && y >= 0 && y < theGrid.grid[0].length) {
            return theGrid.grid[x][y];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static function clear():void {
        if(!theGrid.grid) {
            return;
        }
        for(var x:int = 0; x < theGrid._width; x++) {
            for(var y:int = 0; y < theGrid._height; y++) {
                theGrid.grid[x][y].clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function createGrid(width:int, height:int):Grid {
        if(theGrid) {
            return theGrid;
        }
        var g:Grid = new Grid(o, width, height);
        theGrid = g;
        return g;
    }


    public static function draw(graphics:Graphics, width:Number, height:Number):void {
        if(!theGrid.grid) {
            return;
        }
        graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x555555);
        for(var x:int = 0; x < theGrid._width; x++) {
            for(var y:int = 0; y < theGrid._height; y++) {
                theGrid.grid[x][y].draw(graphics, width, height);
            }
        }
    }


    public static function getGrid():Grid {
        if(theGrid) {
            return theGrid;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static function reset():void {
        if(!theGrid.grid) {
            return;
        }
        for(var x:int = 0; x < theGrid._width; x++) {
            for(var y:int = 0; y < theGrid._height; y++) {
                theGrid.grid[x][y].reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AStar.as

```
package com.rocketmandevelopment.grid {
import com.rocketmandevelopment.grid.Cell;
import com.rocketmandevelopment.math.Vector2D;

[SWF(width=510, height=550, backgroundColor=0, fps=30)]
public class AStar {
    public static var heuristic:Function = manhattan;

    public function AStar() {
    }

    public static function aStar(start:Vector2D, end:Vector2D):Array {
        Grid.reset();
        var open:Array = [Grid.cellAt(start.x, start.y)];
        open[0].isOpen = true;
        var closed:Array = [];
        var currentCell:Cell;
        var path:Array;

        while(true) {
            if(open.length == 0) {
                break;
            }
            currentCell = getLowestF(open);
            if(currentCell.x == end.x && currentCell.y == end.y) {
                path = [currentCell];
                while(true) {
                    path.push(currentCell.parent);
                    currentCell = currentCell.parent;
                    if(!currentCell.parent) {
                        path.reverse();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            closed.push(currentCell);
            currentCell.isClosed = true;
            var n:Array = currentCell.neighbors;
            for(var i:int = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
                if(n[i] == null || !n[i].isWalkable) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!n[i].isOpen && !n[i].isClosed) {
                    open.push(n[i]);
                    n[i].isOpen = true;
                    if(isDiagonal(currentCell, n[i])) {
                        n[i].g = 1.4;
                    } else {
                        n[i].g = 1;
                    }
                    n[i].parent = currentCell;
                    n[i].g += n[i].parent.g;
                    n[i].h = heuristic(n[i], end);
                    n[i].f = n[i].g + n[i].h;
                } else {
                    var tg:Number;
                    if(isDiagonal(currentCell, n[i])) {
                        tg = 1.4;
                    } else {
                        tg = 1
                    }
                    tg += currentCell.g;
                    if(tg < n[i].g) {
                        n[i].g = tg;
                        n[i].f = n[i].g + n[i].h;
                        n[i].parent = currentCell;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static function diagonal(current:Cell, end:Vector2D):Number {
        var xDistance:int = Math.abs(current.x - end.x);
        var yDistance:int = Math.abs(current.y - end.y);
        if(xDistance > yDistance) {
            return yDistance + (xDistance - yDistance);
        } else {
            return xDistance + (yDistance - xDistance);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static function manhattan(current:Cell, end:Vector2D):Number {
        return Math.abs(current.x - end.x) + Math.abs(current.y + end.y);
    }

    private static function getLowestF(list:Array):Cell {
        list.sortOn("f", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
        return list.pop();
    }

    private static function isDiagonal(center:Cell, other:Cell):Boolean {
        if(center.x != other.x && center.y != other.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this in your Main.AS starting class of your Main.FLA file, or you can do the same in the action script project in flash builder, should work the same

```
            var g:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite();

        Grid.createGrid(10,10);
        Grid.draw(g.graphics, 50, 50);

        var _grid:Grid = Grid.getGrid();
        var cell: Cell = _grid.grid[c][r]
        var bestPath: Array = AStar.aStar( sCell, eCell);
```

explanation:
 create the new Sprite to have access to the "graphics"

create a grid with X number of columns and Y number of rows

draw the grid with the sprite graphics, and the width and height you want

fetch the grid instance that you just created

fetch the cell from the  grid, using columns and rows integers

find the best path between starting cell and ending cell, you would may need to convert Cell into Vector2D

something like this should point you in the right direction